# electromagnet question

Tags: batteries, electromagnetism, wire, solenoid

I have an electromagnet (just a nail and wire).  I linked the nail/wire to 1.5 AA battery, nothing.  9V and 12V, nothing.  I then linked the nail/wire to a 6V lantern battery and it picked up the filings.

My question is, why did it fry the copper wire?  The other, higher voltage batteries (new) did not.

Comment: This is actually more of a battery question.

Comment: You are right, you have a nail and wire. Not an electromagnet. What is the difference between AA and lantern battries, and what is fry your wire? Is this a homework based on a textbook? Do not expect answers just by guess!

Answer (score 4):

A battery is not a perfect voltage source with infinite power abilities. A battery is usually an adequate voltage source for reasonable load demands placed on it. Every battery has an ESR (effective series resistance) and this can be seen to get bigger as the battery loses it energy. The ESR limits the ability to drive current and this also means it limits the current into a short circuit.

Your AA battery, your 9V source and your 12V source (without knowing the specs and presuming you wired them correctly) do not generate enough current to attract iron filings.

On the other hand your lantern battery does have the grunt to push enough current round the coils on your nail. It fried the wire because the current is too much for the wire. If you want to make an electromagnet then observe these rules: -

Force = \$\dfrac{(amps\cdot turns)^2\cdot \mu_0\cdot A}{2\cdot g^2}\$

Where

- A is cross sectional area of the nail (larger diameters make better EMs)
- g is gap to your filings from the end of the nail
- \$\mu_0\$ is 4\$\pi\$ x \$10^{-7}\$

Amps and turns and diameter all make a better magnet. If you double the turns the force is quadrupled. Ditto amps and diameter.

Comment: I would like to expand on the "fried the wire" thing. Pretend for a moment you have a perfect 6 volt source with no output resistance. Divide six by .0001. Thats how much current would flow out of it, which is monumental. The internal resistances of those batteries prevents what could otherwise have been a significant fireball. Proper electromagnets have lots and lots of wire, to get more magnetic field, and provide more resistance. They also benefit from low voltage current controlled sources.

Answer (score 1):

Imax = Volts/Resistance.

Resistance will be low so the battery capacity to provide current will be the limiting factor.

A good AA battery will provide a few amps - maybe 10A for a good quality NimH for a small wire. Less for AAA.

12V type that you used not known - if it was a car battery then you'd have no wire. If a small appliance battery < AAA in size then far less current than an AAA.

A Lantern battery of good quality and type MAY supply 20A + for a short while.

Power loss increases as the square of current.
2 x current =- 4 x power dissipation. 
4 x current = 16 x power dissipation.

"Magnetic power" is related to amps x turns.
More current increases the pickup power BUT also energy dissipation.

Use FAR more turns for much more "magnetic power" and much much less power dissipation.